# Rust passing closures and they lifetime

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

Hi I try to pass my closure to [mockall](https://crates.io/crates/mockall) crate returning function in following way:

```rs
pub fn set_dialog_game_selection(dialogs: &mut Box<MockAsk>, steam_id: String) {
    dialogs
        .expect_ask_for_game_decision_if_needed_and_set_game_to_launch()
        .returning(ask_for_game_decision_if_needed_return_mock(steam_id));
}

pub fn ask_for_game_decision_if_needed_return_mock<'x, 'y>(
    steam_id: String,
) -> Box<dyn Fn(&'x mut REvilConfig, &'y mut REvilManagerState) -> ResultDialogsErr<()> + Send> {
    let default = move |_: &'x mut REvilConfig, state: &'y mut REvilManagerState| {
        state.selected_game_to_launch = Some(steam_id.clone());
        Ok(())
    };
    return Box::new(default);
}
```

but I get

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src\tests\integration.rs:128:14
    |
128 |             .returning(ask_for_game_decision_if_needed_return_mock(steam_id.to_string()));
    |              ^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
    |
    = note: expected associated type `<dyn Fn(&mut configStruct::REvilConfig, &mut rManager_header::REvilManagerState) -> Result<(), error_stack::Report<DialogsErrors>> + Send as FnOnce<(&mut configStruct::REvilConfig, &mut rManager_header::REvilManagerState)>>::Output`
               found associated type `<dyn Fn(&mut configStruct::REvilConfig, &mut rManager_header::REvilManagerState) -> Result<(), error_stack::Report<DialogsErrors>> + Send as FnOnce<(&mut configStruct::REvilConfig, &mut rManager_header::REvilManagerState)>>::Output`
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
   --> src\dialogs\dialogs.rs:54:10
    |
54  |     ) -> ResultDialogsErr<()>;
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

P.S I'm writting mod manager for Resident Evil game that's why "REvil" :p

P.S2 In the end I managed to rewrite it like:

```rust
pub fn set_dialog_game_selection(dialogs: &mut Box<MockAsk>, steam_id: String) {
    dialogs
        .expect_ask_for_game_decision_if_needed_and_set_game_to_launch()
        .returning(move |_, state| {
            set_game_decision(steam_id.clone(), state);
            Ok(())
        });
}

pub fn set_game_decision(steam_id: String, state: &mut REvilManagerState) {
    state.selected_game_to_launch = Some(steam_id);
}
```

But why my first approach doeasn't work? :(

Function signature I'm trying to mock is as follow:

```rust
pub type ResultDialogsErr<T> = Result<T, DialogsErrors>;

fn ask_for_game_decision_if_needed_and_set_game_to_launch(
   &mut self,
   config: &mut REvilConfig,
   state: &mut REvilManagerState,
) -> ResultDialogsErr<()>;
```

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example?

Comment: Agree with @ChayimFriedman. Can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Hey sure here is link to playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=057c94d399d4b8133a327a57334024fc but you have to copy it and use locally as mockall crate is not supported there. I'm using latest mockall.
mockall = "0.11.1"

When you uncomment set_dialog_game_selection_2 function then you have issue I'm talking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the manual lifetime annotations, it works:

```
pub fn ask_for_game_decision_if_needed_return_mock(
    steam_id: String,
) -> Box<dyn Fn(&mut REvilConfig, &mut REvilManagerState) -> DynResult<()> + Send> {
    let default = move |_: &mut REvilConfig, state: &mut REvilManagerState| {
        state.selected_game_to_launch = Some(steam_id.clone());
        Ok(())
    };
    return Box::new(default);
}
```

Comment: Yup it works... Interesting I've added liftime annotations because compiler was asking for them. Maybe after many tries I ended up with code that no longer needed them but I didn't test it. @Finomnis Thank you for checking it:)